# Fillable forms with compiled output

Tags: pdftex, forms

I am interested in the following. 
A pdf file has to contain 3 forms, say A B and C. 
Form A is fillable, and an input can be a latex mathematical code, like 
$\frac{\sin x}{x}$, whatever. 
Form B is a pushbutton.
Form C then returns the result of latex compilation of the input formula. 
Then, w/o recompiling the pdf file, I input another code, eg $\tan^2(3x)$, 
klick B and get the compiled formula in C. 
Is this doable within a latex file? 
Thanks for attention
Vlad

Comment: you want to embed a tex typesetting engine _within_ the pdf file?????

Comment: Welcome! Basically, no. This is not doable within a LaTeX file. You might be able to do something clever with javascript and a TeX compiler behind the scenes, but, in the final analysis, you cannot compile code without compiling it.